# how to find a dxf entity is inside another entity?

Tags: python, vertex, dxf

[3d letter from DXF File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGzKe.png)

In the image there is a 3d letter O from dxf file.
O represented as two rounds.so there is two entity.

How can i detect one entity is inside another (in case of o,how to know small round is inside big round)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, calculate the bounding box around both entities.
This has the form of a tuple, say `(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)`. You can think of this as a box with sides parallel to the x- and y-axes that surrounds the entity.

If both the x-values from the first bounding box are in between the xmin and xmax of the second bounding box, *and* the same goes for the y-values, the first bounding box is inside the second one.

Note that this technique is an *approximation*. It is possible to create entities that overlap while their bounding boxes don't intersect.

Comment: implemented the logic.but is there any way to find the same if entity overlap

Comment: There is an overlap if *one* x-coordinate *and* *one* y-coordinate fall between the respective coordinates of the second bounding box.